# Bibliography & \include

Tags: bibliographies, include

I am working on a big project divided, and i've decided that the best way to go about it is to write separately each chapter and then simply used the \include command on the main document. However, I will also need to bibliography. I thought about using the thebibliography environment but i am confused. where would i need to do this? In the main document? if so, would I still be able to use the \cite function on each of the individual documents?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: yes `\include` files are processed as a single document you can use \cite and \ref across chapters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all the citing in your subfiles as well. Just use a structure as shown below:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\input{header} % header.tex in the same folder containing your preamble
%\includeonly{chapter/Chapter1} % optional to compile just one file

\begin{document}
\include{chapter/Chapter1}
\include{chapter/Chapter2}
\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem{atuning}Volker Wollny (Hrsg.): {\textit Amiga--Tuning}.
                 Interest--Verlag, Augsburg, 1996.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```